# Relacionamento datas em resultado de query SQL no Oracle

Tags: sql, query, oracle

Boa tarde,

Ao realizar a seguinte consulta 
`SELECT CD_ATENDIMENTO,DT_ATENDIMENTO FROM ATENDIME`
obtenho o seguinte retorno

[image: Consulta]

Porem, preciso que retorne apenas os resultados que tiverem menos de 90 dias de diferença entre um e outro, que seria o 4º e o 5º registro.

Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Alexandre, o campo DT_ATENDIMENTO é do tipo date?

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar o seguinte:

```
select CD_ATENDIMENTO, DT_ATENDIMENTO
from ATENDIME
where DT_ATENDIMENTO >= trunc(sysdate - interval '60' DAY)
```

Com isso, você trará os registros com `DT_ATENDIMENTO` maior ou igual a 60 antes da data de hoje (caso seja outro parâmetro, pode alterar o *sysdate*)

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, ele quer os registros que tenham diferença menor entre um e outro e não necessariamente entre a data atual ou uma data específica. Mas vamos aguardar a manifestação dele.

Comment: Correto Filipe, eu utilizei o comando LAG para tentar fazer essa comparação, porem cai em outro problema, nao esta agrupado pelo funcionario. Explicando melhor, preciso filtrar todos os pacientes que ja foram internados e tiveram alta, porem reinternaram até 30 dias apos.

Answer (score 0):

Segue o comando que fiz e o resultado

`SELECT ATENDIME.CD_ATENDIMENTO, ATENDIME.CD_PACIENTE, PACIENTE.NM_PACIENTE, ATENDIME.DT_ATENDIMENTO, ATENDIME.DT_ALTA,LAG(DT_ALTA,1)OVER (ORDER BY ATENDIME.CD_PACIENTE) AS ULT

      FROM ATENDIME 
  JOIN (SELECT CD_PACIENTE FROM ATENDIME 
        WHERE CD_LEITO IN (SELECT CD_LEITO FROM LEITO WHERE CD_UNID_INT IN (10,11,18))
        GROUP BY CD_PACIENTE HAVING COUNT(CD_PACIENTE)> 1) A 
    ON A.CD_PACIENTE = ATENDIME.CD_PACIENTE

  JOIN PACIENTE ON PACIENTE.CD_PACIENTE = ATENDIME.CD_PACIENTE

WHERE CD_LEITO IN (SELECT CD_LEITO FROM LEITO WHERE CD_UNID_INT IN (10,11,18)) 
  ORDER BY  ATENDIME.CD_PACIENTE`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
A partir dai faria o comparativo do campo ULT com a DT_ATENDIMENTO, porem ele estra trazendo os dados de outros pacientes, e o necessario é listar apenas os que tiveram a reinternação até 30 dias apos sua Alta